# MagentoCrawler fills apache access log

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-enterprise, magento-1

We are running Magento Entperise 1.14.4.2.

Access log file is getting filled with "MagentoCrawler" entries and drags performance.

It stops after the server reboot. But starts back the next day.

Added .htaccess entries. But that did't stop it.

Any Thoughts?

Thanks for your help and Merry Christmas!

Comment: Can someone respond please?

Answer (score 2):

You just need to disable Full Page Cache Auto Generation from the Magento Admin.

**System > Configuration > System (Under Advanced) > Enable Page Cache Auto Generation**

Be sure to check each store individually since this setting can differ at the store view level.

When this is enabled, a cron will run daily which will attempt to pre-cache all URLs within the enterprise_url_rewrite table by loading each page via a curl request. Pre-caching pages is strategy that can work well, but keep in mind that this will cause a backup in your Magento cron until this process finishes. For sites that utilize Magento's built in cache crawler, I recommend using AOE Scheduler (https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_Scheduler) to manage your crons. With this tool, you can run a separate cron for the crawler so that your other Magento jobs can run without getting delayed.